Route structure and layouts problem in Next.js
I have a web-app I want to implement something like this, I already have Navbar(Header) and footer components.

How would my file structure look like, not sure if i should use grouping because it doesn't solve it.
I tried route grouping but as a beginner I do not know how to go about solving this

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

Parallel routes might do the trick for you. Try adding Header and Footer as slots, and conditionally render them as per your requirement.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/parallel-routes

You can use slot as one of the comments above suggested but if you don't want to do that, I have two other solutions for you.

Route Grouping - Route grouping can actually work you because in each route group, you can define a layout which all the routes in that group will use. Each route group can have a layout defined as layout.tsx, this is your easiest solution.

You can create the Header and Footer components and import them separately on each route you want to use. This is also easy too but not smart idea.



Adding a Header and Footer in a Wrapper Layer-like layout. tsof a grouped route does not seem to be a good idea since you don't need a header in a sub-route like app/create/step1.
It is better to create an array of routes in which you want to show the Header and Footer.
const HEADER_REQD_ROUTES = ["/app", "/app/overview", "/app/create", "/login", "/"];
const FOOTER_REQD_ROUTES = ["/", "/login];

Now In you Header and Footer component, Render these component only if current   route is included the above arrays.
{HEADER_REQD_ROUTES.includes(currentPathname) && <Header/>}
{FOOTER_REQD_ROUTES.includes(currentPathname) && <Footer/>}

You can get the pathname form next/navigation.

My advise is to take a look at Next.js docs about pages and layout if you are using the app folder, and this link if you are using the page folder
If you are using the app folder, the root layout will always be there, so in your case I think the best way is to have it without the header and the footer so the create steps stay clear of them. Then manually import them to / and /login. under app/ you can have the layout  with only the header
If you are using the page folder, you just manually import them where are they needed.
